# Use emoji for UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, emoji

Is it possible to use an Emoji as an UIIMage?  I would like to change the annotation pins from pins to country flags.  Since the country flags unicode characters...

let canadaFlag = "\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E6}"

Thanks!!

Comment: Just add the emoji to a `UILabel` and create a `UIImage` from the label (see the linked duplicate).